# Why were my examples edited out

Tags: support

In Can I bring computer parts (*eg: Intel CPU*) from US to the UK? (emphasis mine) my answer contained examples of Intel CPUs, examples that I actually researched to make sure they are correct (the  i7-7800X is above the limit at newegg but below at amazon) https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/98936/4188 and yet they were edited out. Why? I feel like reverting the edit but don't want an edit war.

Comment: You're probably better off @ tagging Jan on the answer, as they may not look here...

Comment: @chx I agree with you, that your answer was fine as it was, and that Jan should not have edited it out. I'll ask him to explain.